# how to print values in control - MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to print values which I am storing in object on the controller. I tried searching for the answer but I didn't find proper answer. Please help

```
//my code in control  

 public ActionResult PrintOutput()
        {
                ModalClass myObject = new ModalClass              
                myObject.load(str);
                ViewBag.myOject = myOject.ToString();
                return View("PositionPrint");
        }




   //In view page I have created a **PartialView**. Inside partial view I
   // have given below code alone


         @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.myOject)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use object as a variable name - it's a keyword of the language. Your controller usually "prints out" values by returning a view that is populated with the data from the view bag or custom model. If you just need to print a raw html string - `@Html.Raw(myObject)`

In your controller action, tough, you need to put the value somewhere so the view can access it. For example:

```
public ActionResult PrintOutput(sting str)
{
   Modalclass myObject = new Modalclass(); 
   myObject.load(str);

   ViewBag.myObject = myObject; //probably at least ToString() call is due here
   return View();
}
```

And in the view use `@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.myObject)` to print what's in it.

P.S. But you really should never try to print out a contents of an entire object. That is a rather meaningless act. (except for debugging) Be specific. Each data property in you object should be printed to a specific ui elements on the view.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! [ViewBag._ObjectPM = _ObjectPM;] I have given code I mentioned above and in return [return View("PositionPrint", _ObjectPM);] and in partial view page [@Html.Raw(@ViewBag._Object)].. But no luck. I feel I am missing something

Comment: What's in the object. What is the source for Modalclass? Provide more code regarding the problem in the question body so we have a material to inverstigate =)

Comment: What is ModalClass? Where is it's source?

Answer (score 0):

Whenver possible, try to Avoid Dynamic Magic Variable like `ViewBag` and `ViewData`. These Magic variables makes your code ugly. **Always try to use strong types**.

Have a `ViewModel` for your view. Ex : If you want to print the details about the Customer. You can create a ViewModel ( it is just a POCO) for that like this

```
public class CustomerPrint
{
  public string FirstName { set;get;}
  public string JobTitle { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your Controller action, set the values of this and pass that to your view.

```
public ActionResult PrintOutput()
{ 
  var customerPrintVM=new CustomerPrint();
  customerPrintVM.FirstName="Jon";
  customerPrintVM.JobTitle="Developer";
  return View(customerPrintVM);
}
```

Since we are passing the object of CustomerPrint class, Our view should be strongly typed to this class. So change your view like this.

```
@model CustomerPrint

<h2>This is your view content</h2>
<p>@Model.FirstName</p>
<p>@Model.JobTitle</p>
@Html.Raw(Model.FirstName)
```

If your ViewModel class resides in a namespace,you may need to give the fullpath to the class in the first like like this

```
@model YourNameSpaceName.CustomerPrint
```

You can access the Properties of your Model in this Format `Model.PropertyName` (Ex : `Model.FirstName`) and in razor, you need to use `@` if the expression is not already inside a codeblock.